# Pandas data manipulation with date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, data-manipulation

I have two df, I want to manipulation the one on the basis of other. My df1 looks like this
date format is mm-dd-yyyy

| Date | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 = col_2/col_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 100 | 110 | 1.1 |
| 02/01/2021 | 110 | 110 | 1 |
| 03/01/2021 | 120 | 132 | 1.1 |
| 04/01/2021 | 100 | 120 | 1.2 |

Now my other data frame look like this

| Date | col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | A | 110 |
| 01/01/2021 | B | 110 |
| 01/01/2021 | C | 132 |
| 01/01/2021 | D | 120 |
| 02/01/2021 | A | 110 |
| 02/01/2021 | B | 110 |
| 02/01/2021 | C | 132 |
| 03/01/2021 | D | 120 |

Now I want to multiply "col_3" of df1 to "col_2" of df2 on date wise. Please help

I tried this

```
def (df1,df2,ind) #ind is integer for month
    df2['col_2'] = df2['col_2'] * df1['col_3'].iloc(ind-1)
    return df2
```

my desired output look like

| Date | col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | A | 121 |
| 01/01/2021 | B | 121 |
| 01/01/2021 | C | 145.2 |
| 01/01/2021 | D | 132 |
| 02/01/2021 | A | 110 |
| 02/01/2021 | B | 110 |
| 02/01/2021 | C | 132 |
| 03/01/2021 | D | 132 |

Comment: kindly add your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use `Date` column as index of both dataframes then apply your operation:

```
df2['col_3'] = df2.set_index('Date')['col_2'] \
                  .mul(df1.set_index('Date').reindex(df2['Date'])['col_3']).values
print(df2)

# Output
         Date col_1  col_2  col_3
0  01/01/2021     A    110  121.0
1  01/01/2021     B    110  121.0
2  01/01/2021     C    132  145.2
3  01/01/2021     D    120  132.0
4  02/01/2021     A    110  110.0
5  02/01/2021     B    110  110.0
6  02/01/2021     C    132  132.0
7  03/01/2021     D    120  132.0
```

Comment: Can you help me with this one also? [Question_stackof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163660/data-manipulation-on-the-basis-of-yoy-basis) @Corralien